# how to include some data in 2 tables asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for my bad English..

I have 3 tables, like this.. I use ViewModel

```
public class CostumVM
{
    public rol_tb_form1 rol_tb_form1 { get; set; }
    public tb_update_status_moc tb_update_status_moc { get; set; }
    public rol_tb_ramanalysis rol_tb_ramanalysis { get; set; }
}
```

in that table I joined them with this code

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmoc()
    {

        var updateemoc = from a in db.rol_tb_form1
                         join b in db.tb_update_status_moc on a.no_mocx equals b.no_mocx
                         join c in db.rol_tb_ramanalysis on a.id_ram equals c.id
                         select new CostumVM { rol_tb_form1 = a, tb_update_status_moc = b, rol_tb_ramanalysis = c};

        return View(updateemoc);
    }
```

but, I have a problem, data in table *rol_tb_form1* and *rol_tb_update_status_moc* is 300++, but data in *rol_tb_ramanalysis* just 7, if I use join so in view just show 7 data. I need to show 300++ in table *rol_tb_form1* and include 7 data betwen table *rol_tb_form1*..

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called LEFT OUTER JOIN which can be implemented using LINQ with `GroupJoin` (or `join ... into` for query syntax), the idea is if some key does not have a group (matched from the right source), a group of empty elements (for that key) will be added in the result. We can project the result with that empty group to have the desired result. 
For your code it should be something like this:

```
var updateemoc = from a in db.rol_tb_form1
                 join b in db.tb_update_status_moc on a.no_mocx equals b.no_mocx
                 join c in db.rol_tb_ramanalysis on a.id_ram equals c.id into g
                 from d in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new CostumVM { 
                            rol_tb_form1 = a, 
                            tb_update_status_moc = b, 
                            rol_tb_ramanalysis = d
                        };
```

Note about `DefaultIfEmpty`, without using it you will miss the result corresponding to when the key does not match, by using it the empty set will turn into a default set including just 1 default element (null for class, and in this case it's null). So for all non-matching entries, you will have `rol_tb_ramanalysis` as `null` in the result. That should be the desired result you need.

Comment: @RahmanKryptonz the remaining is the same, don't you see that it just replaces the result from your `updateemoc` variable?

Comment: I dont know how to show in Razor View, I use `@item.rol_tb_ramanalysis.ram_criticality` I get error `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_unubygks.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` @KingKing

Comment: @RahmanKryptonz as I said before, in the result set this `item.rol_tb_ramanalysis` can be null (and there are just 7 having non-null value). So you need to check null before accessing it. For null value, it should just display empty string.

Comment: @RahmanKryptonz OK, if the answer helped you, please accept it to help other know that the answer is correct and can be followed.